# Sympy substitution, substituting many variable in many equations

Tags: python, sympy, substitution

I have a system of 9 equations and 9 unknowns.  I can do this in Mathcad, wxMaxima or Mathematica.  The problem arises when I have a list of equations.

```
leq0 = [eq0,eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq17]
```

One of the variables is v3 and another is a2. I want to substitute

```
leq1 = []
for eq in leq0:
    eq.subs([(v3,v),(a2,a)])
    print(eq)
    leq1.append(eq)
```

the `eq.subs([(v3,v),(a2,a)])` does not do anything
neither does manually

```
eq = leq0[6]
eq.subs([(v3,v),(a2,a)])
```

When I print eq the equations look right.

```
a0*t01**2/2 + j*t01**3/6 + t01*v0 + x0 - x1
a0*t01 + j*t01**2/2 + v0 - v2
a0 - a1 + j*t01
a1*t12**2/2 + t12*v1 + x1 - x2
a1*t12 + v1 - v2
a2*t23**2/2 - j*t23**3/6 + t23*v2 + x2 - x3
a2*t23 - j*t23**2/2 + v2 - v3
a2 - a3 - j*t23
t01 + t12 + t23
```

Why can't I do a simple substitution.   I can manually edit `v3` to `v` but this is a simpler example of a more complex problem.   I can make these substitutions in other math packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subs` doesn't overwrite the variable that contains the expression, it returns the resulting expression after substitution.

```
changed = original.subs({var1: value1, var2: value2})
```

In your case, you are not capturing the substituted expression.

```
leq1 = []
for eq in leq0:
    eq.subs([(v3,v),(a2,a)]) # result not captured
    print(eq)                # `eq` still has original expression
    leq1.append(eq)
```

To fix this, you can overwrite `eq` with substituted expression before adding to the new list:

```
eq = eq.subs({v3: v, a2: a})
```

or append the substitution directly:

```
for eq in leq0:
    leq1.append(eq.subs({v3: v, a2: a})
```

---

Note: I'm calling your equations as expressions because they contain only one side of the equation. `subs` will work fine for equations that have both sides too.

```
eq6 = Eq(a2*t23 - j*t23**2/2 + v2, v3)
pprint(eq2.subs({v3: v, a2: a}))
```

See the result on [sympy live](http://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=a%2C%20v%2C%20a2%2C%20t23%2C%20j%2C%20v2%2C%20v3%20%3D%20symbols(%22a%2C%20v%2C%20a2%2C%20t23%2C%20j%2C%20v2%2C%20v3%22)%0Aeq6%20%3D%20Eq(a2*t23%20-%20j*t23**2%2F2%20%2B%20v2%2C%20v3)%0Aeq6%0A%23--%0Aeq6.subs(%7Bv3%3A%20v%2C%20a2%3A%20a%7D)%0A%23--%0A).

Comment: It works!.  Thanx so much.  This also explains why I would get a result when I did this manually in a shell.

Comment: @user1402208 you are right, the shell simply prints the result of last evaluated expression. If my answer solves your issue, could you mark it as accepted answer?